# Geofencing and GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, geofencing

I am using Geofencing for my app and i followed the steps declared [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)
But everytime i try initializing GoogleApiClient i am unable to recieve any call backs..following is my code..

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks)this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

i get a force close error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

Code in onCreate()

```
geoFence = new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId("DVSN")
            .setCircularRegion(18.5553785, 73.8164671, 10)
            .setExpirationDuration(43200000)
            .setTransitionTypes(
                    Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                            | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build();
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
```

private methods

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofence(geoFence);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent
    // back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: Do you call mGoogleApiClient.connect()?

Comment: yes i have called  it in  onstart() method.

Comment: Are you using mGoogleApiClient before onConnected() is called?

Comment: onConnected is never called. The above code is written in onCreate and mGoogleApiClient.connect() is written in onStart()

Comment: please give us more code

Comment: edited for more code

Comment: Move all of that code in onCreate() to onConnected(), you're using mGoogleApiClient before it's connected.

Comment: Thanks bro..it worked

Answer (score 0):

First connect your `GoogleApiClient`, After then add Geofences to `GeofencingApi`.

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                  @Override
                  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
                     addGeofencesOnLoad();
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                   }
              }).build();
mApiClient.connect();


public void addGeofencesOnLoad() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

 try {
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
 } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
    logSecurityException(securityException);
 }
}
```

First, use `Geofence.Builder` to create a geofence, setting the desired radius, duration, and transition types for the geofence. For example, to populate a list object named `mGeofenceList`

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
// Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
// geofence.
.setRequestId(entry.getKey())

.setCircularRegion(
        entry.getValue().latitude,
        entry.getValue().longitude,
        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
)
.setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
.build());
```

The following snippet uses the `GeofencingRequest` class and its nested `GeofencingRequestBuilder` class to specify the geofences to monitor and to set how related geofence events are triggered

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

The following snippet shows how to define a `PendingIntent` that starts an `IntentService`

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```